# Checking if the Firestore key has value

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am looping trough a snapshot retrieved from a Firestore database getting values into my custom object with conditional unwrapping like the example below. It works fine as long as the key has a value, but as soon as it is empty i get an exception on line `if let temp = document.get("windGust") as! String?` (See error further down)

I thought conditional unwrapping was supposed to handle this ? 
Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to handle this in code? If the value of `windGust` is empty it should just ignore it and continue.

```
    db.collection("yrData").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

        for document in snapshot!.documents {

            let yrData = YrData()
            if let temp = document.get("windGust") as! String?
            {
                yrData.windGust = temp
            }
```

The error:

> Could not cast value of type '_NSZeroData' (0x7fff87d0b5b8) to 'NSString' (0x7fff87d0eee8).
>   2020-01-16 21:29:23.417663+0100 Victoria[13603:708774] Could not cast value of type '_NSZeroData' (0x7fff87d0b5b8) to 'NSString' (0x7fff87d0eee8).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not an answer to my question, but this is a solution:

Instead of using:

```
            if let temp = document.get("windGust") as! String?
            {
                yrData.windGust = temp
            }
```

Use data() like this:

```
yrData.windGust = data["windGust"] as? String ?? ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to use the null coalescing operator.

Something like that would read; if windGust lookup is not a string, assign an empty string.

```
yrData.windGust = document.get("windGust") as? String ?? ""
```